# permutation composition in *permutation bar* space, can it be expressed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For a permutation $\pi\in S_n$ we define its bar permutation $\bar\pi$ as:
$$\bar\pi=[\bar\pi(1),...\bar\pi(n)]\colon\; \bar\pi(i)=\#\{j\le i\colon \pi(j)\ge\pi(i)\}$$
If we define *bar space* as $B_n=[1]\times[2]\times ...[n-1]\times[n]$,  the bar operation is a one-to-one map from $S_n$ to $B_n$ (see problem 3.16 in "Combinatorial Problems and Exercises" by Lovász). $B_n$ has the advantage that it decomposes the permutation to independent components (say if permutation is uniformly chosen at random its components in $B_n$ space are indpendent)

Moroever, for two permutations $\pi,\sigma\in S_n$ permutation composition is defined as: 
$$\sigma\circ\pi = [\sigma(\pi(1)),\sigma(\pi(2)),...,\sigma(\pi(n))]$$

Is it possible to express composition in the bar space, i.e., to compute $\overline{\sigma\circ\pi}$ as a function of $\bar\sigma$ and $\bar\pi$?

Comment: Have a look at Lehmer code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code#The_code ... How is the Lehmer codes of the composition of permutations related to the Lehmer codes of the original permutations ? ... Great Question !

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit thanks! Lehmer's code is clearly tightly related to bar operation here. In fact, if we make the inequalities to strict inequality in definition of $\bar\sigma$, and set $\sigma'=[n+1-\sigma(n),n+1-\sigma(n-1),...,n+1-\sigma(1)]$ then $\bar\sigma=L(\sigma')$

Comment: I think you're going to have a tough time for general $\pi$. It should however be doable for the case when $\pi$ is an adjacent transposition $(i,i+1)$

Comment: @AlexR. how about a combination of Lehmer's code and bar space? Like if we have $L(\sigma)$ and $\bar\pi$ or vice versa? My goal is to work with the composition in a decomposed space (that components are independent of each other). Doesn't matter what kind of decomposition though.